# Rails 5: Truncate some with read more & hide links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I'm  using the following code in order to `truncate` some text. Everything works just fine as you can see below. Currently both the `Read more` and `Hide` links appear at all times. Is there a way to hide the `Hide` link when the `Read more` is not clicked and show the `Hide` link when the `Read more` link is clicked?

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
<% if product.description.size > 100 %>
  <span class="truncated-paragraph-<%= product.id %>">
    <%= truncate product.description, length: 100 %>
  </span>
  <span class="normal-paragraph-<%= product.id %>" style="display: none;">
    <%= product.description %>
  </span>
  <a href="#" class="read-more-<%= product.id %>">Read More</a>
  <a href="#" class="read-less-<%= product.id %>">Hide</a>
<% else %>
  <%= product.description %>
<% end %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('[class^="read-more"]').click(function(element) {
    element.preventDefault()
    $(`.truncated-paragraph-${elId($(this))}`).hide()
    $(`.normal-paragraph-${elId($(this))}`).show()
  })

  $('[class^="read-less"]').click(function(element) {
    element.preventDefault()
    $(`.normal-paragraph-${elId($(this))}`).hide()
    $(`.truncated-paragraph-${elId($(this))}`).show()
  })

  function elId(element) {
    let elClassName = element.attr('class').split('-')
    return elClassName[elClassName.length - 1]
  }
</script>
```

```js
$('[class^="read-more"]').click(function(element) {
  element.preventDefault()
  $(`.truncated-paragraph-${elId($(this))}`).hide()
  $(`.normal-paragraph-${elId($(this))}`).show()
})

$('[class^="read-less"]').click(function(element) {
  element.preventDefault()
  $(`.normal-paragraph-${elId($(this))}`).hide()
  $(`.truncated-paragraph-${elId($(this))}`).show()
})

function elId(element) {
  let elClassName = element.attr('class').split('-')
  return elClassName[elClassName.length - 1]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="truncated-paragraph-1">
  Morbi non est nec mi vulputate varius vel ac mi. In efficitur bibendum nibh nec fringilla. Integer nec est blandit, ullamcorper leo ...
</span>
<span class="normal-paragraph-1" style="display: none;">
  Morbi non est nec mi vulputate varius vel ac mi. In efficitur bibendum nibh nec fringilla. Integer nec est blandit, ullamcorper leo iaculis, blandit dui. Suspendisse sem mauris, maximus quis porta elementum, fermentum in dolor. Curabitur egestas arcu ante. Praesent a efficitur leo. Proin molestie turpis in sapien porta varius. Sed nisl enim, blandit ac orci in, iaculis consectetur tellus.

Quisque sapien felis, gravida in leo eget, dictum tempus felis. Ut pulvinar ex nisi, et rutrum leo dignissim at. Integer facilisis facilisis odio. Quisque consequat, ex eu sodales posuere, orci tellus accumsan justo, vitae finibus turpis turpis et tortor. Praesent luctus consequat tortor vel egestas. Suspendisse finibus interdum varius. Curabitur facilisis aliquet diam ac aliquet. Phasellus in felis placerat, gravida velit at, pulvinar nulla. Mauris ut faucibus felis, vitae semper elit. Aenean vel tincidunt leo. Donec varius est a hendrerit eleifend. Maecenas iaculis porta tortor imperdiet blandit. Praesent fermentum mauris metus, eu pulvinar lectus euismod vitae.
</span>
<a href="#" class="read-more-1">Read More</a>
<a href="#" class="read-less-1">Hide</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encapsulate your paragraphs in a parent div so that's it's easier to code the interactions:

```js
$('.read-more').click(function(element) {
  element.preventDefault()
  $(this).parent().find('.truncated-paragraph').hide()
  $(this).parent().find('.normal-paragraph').show()
  $(this).hide()
  $(this).parent().find('.read-less').show()
})

$('.read-less').click(function(element) {
  element.preventDefault()
  $(this).parent().find('.truncated-paragraph').show()
  $(this).parent().find('.normal-paragraph').hide()
  $(this).hide()
  $(this).parent().find('.read-more').show()
})

function elId(element) {
  let elClassName = element.attr('class').split('-')
  return elClassName[elClassName.length - 1]
}
```

```css
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="paragraph">
<span class="truncated-paragraph">
  Morbi non est nec mi vulputate varius vel ac mi. In efficitur bibendum nibh nec fringilla. Integer nec est blandit, ullamcorper leo ...
</span>
<span class="normal-paragraph" style="display: none;">
  Morbi non est nec mi vulputate varius vel ac mi. In efficitur bibendum nibh nec fringilla. Integer nec est blandit, ullamcorper leo iaculis, blandit dui. Suspendisse sem mauris, maximus quis porta elementum, fermentum in dolor. Curabitur egestas arcu ante. Praesent a efficitur leo. Proin molestie turpis in sapien porta varius. Sed nisl enim, blandit ac orci in, iaculis consectetur tellus.

Quisque sapien felis, gravida in leo eget, dictum tempus felis. Ut pulvinar ex nisi, et rutrum leo dignissim at. Integer facilisis facilisis odio. Quisque consequat, ex eu sodales posuere, orci tellus accumsan justo, vitae finibus turpis turpis et tortor. Praesent luctus consequat tortor vel egestas. Suspendisse finibus interdum varius. Curabitur facilisis aliquet diam ac aliquet. Phasellus in felis placerat, gravida velit at, pulvinar nulla. Mauris ut faucibus felis, vitae semper elit. Aenean vel tincidunt leo. Donec varius est a hendrerit eleifend. Maecenas iaculis porta tortor imperdiet blandit. Praesent fermentum mauris metus, eu pulvinar lectus euismod vitae.
</span>

<a href="#" class="read-more">Read More</a>
<a href="#" class="read-less hidden">Hide</a>    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Samy Kacimi. There is a small issue though...  So when I load the page the hide is hidden but when I click on one read more all the hide appear. In case you haven't noticed I have a loop of products if that makes any difference.